# Why len return different values?

Tags: python-3.x

```
c=b.readlines()
print(len(c))
print(len(b.readlines()))
```

this is what I got:
2
0

Why are these two results different?

Answer (score 2):

because you've already read the lines from b and it has nothing left to return

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` is a function with a *side-effect*: it is clearly consuming data from `b`.

So a second invocation may well give you a different result.